# Displaying object values with given properties as children gives error - React and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to display object value with a given property inside a `<th>` or `<td>` tag but it results in a error **Type 'string | ObjectType[keyof ObjectType]' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.**. But weirdly when I console.log(object[key]) everything works perfectly.

Here is the code:

```
interface Props<ObjectType> {
   objects: ObjectType[];
   properties: {
      key: keyof ObjectType;
   }[];
   navigation?(id: number, item?: {}): void;
   children?: boolean;
}

const DisplayTable = <ObjectType extends { id: number }>(props: Props<ObjectType>) => {
   const { objects, properties, navigation, children } = props;

   const displayKeys = (tag: 'th' | 'td', object: ObjectType): JSX.Element[] => {
      return properties.map((propertie) => {
         const { key } = propertie;
         const ChosenTag = `${tag}` as keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements;
         console.log(object[key]); //Works perfectly
         return (
            <ChosenTag key={key as string}>
               {/* Here is the error */}
               {object ? object[key] : firstLetterUppercase(key as string)}
            </ChosenTag>
         );
      });
   };

   return (
     ......
   )
}
```

Comment: I don't seem to get that error, is the code you are using exactly the same?

Comment: The only difference is that I set the object argument optional in my code, but for more simplicity it is required here.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever tried wrap the `{object ? object[key] : firstLetterUppercase(key as string)}` with <></>?
Here is the code...
return (
<ChosenTag key={key as string}>
{/* Here is the error */}
<>
{object ? object[key] : firstLetterUppercase(key as string)}
</>

);
I wish this can help you.

Comment: Perfect it works! But why? I don't understand why we need react fragment here as there is parent element....